# Change the unit value of the distance and time getting from map API in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, time, distance

I am building an android application where I am using google map API to get distance and time between two lat,lng. The problem is sometime I am getting the value in KM and some time in meter.

Is there any way to fix the unit of distance and time value returning from google API.
Here is my code.

```
public class DirectionsJSONParser {

        /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
        public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
            JSONArray jLegs = null;
            JSONArray jSteps = null;
            JSONObject jDistance = null;
            JSONObject jDuration = null;

    try {

        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

        /** Traversing all routes */
        for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
            jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            /** Traversing all legs */
            for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){

                /** Getting distance from the json data */
                jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));

                /** Getting duration from the json data */
                jDuration = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                HashMap<String, String> hmDuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hmDuration.put("duration", jDuration.getString("text"));

                /** Adding distance object to the path */
                path.add(hmDistance);

                /** Adding duration object to the path */
                path.add(hmDuration);

                jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                /** Traversing all steps */
                for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                    String polyline = "";
                    polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);
                    /** Traversing all points */
                    for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                        hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                        path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                }
            routes.add(path);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
    return routes;
    }
    /**
     * Method to decode polyline points
     * Courtesy : jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
     * */
        private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
        (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
        }
    return poly;
    }
```

Here the the function where I get the distance and time in a string.

```
    /**
 * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
 */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {
    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }


    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process

    @Override


    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        String distance = "";
        String duration = "";
        if (result.size() < 1) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
                if (j == 0) {
                    // Get distance from the list
                    distance = (String) point.get("distance");
                    continue;
                } else if (j == 1) { // Get duration from the list
                    duration = (String) point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(10);
            lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Distance:" + distance + ", Duration:" + duration, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
}
```

I need is that the final that return should be KM in distance and HH:MM in hr.

Comment: I assume the value type (meter or km) is specified in the string. Could you not simply convert to km in the cases where meter is returned, or am I misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, looks like you are getting results from the [Direction Web API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro).

In your code,

```
             /** Getting distance from the json data */
            jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
            HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));
```

Notices that you are getting the human-readable distance `"text"`, rather than the integer value `value`.

Look at this piece of JSON from the example in the documentation

```
...
  },
  "distance": {
    "value": 2137146,
    "text": "1,328 mi"
  },
  "start_loc...
...
```

Here, `..leg[0].distance.text` is the human-readable value in miles. What you should get instead is the integer value `..leg[0].distance.value`, which is always in meter.

So in short, get the value in meter, not the text.